# Как убрать окончания на сайтах

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста разобраться с таким вопросом. 
Как убрать окончания у сайта: **http://site.ru/aboutus.html**
Чтобы получилось так:         **http://site.ru/aboutus/**
Если можно, разъясните поподробнее.

Comment: [mod_rewrite][1]

[1]: http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=29&id=740

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Берем и создаем в корне сайта файл `.htaccess`, это эдакая конфигурация для сервера. Там мы пишем:

```
RewriteEngine on - это мы включили "парсер" поданного на сервер url
RewriteRule ^aboutus/$ aboutus.html
```

Первый параметр - это регулярное выражение(шаблон для парсера), все, **что будет к нему подходить**, будет перенаправлено на адрес, указанный во втором параметре

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.